# how to insert DateEntry widget selected by user into mysql database?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, tkinter-entry

how to insert DateEntry widget selected by user into the database?

t1 = DateEntry(self.root)
cal.pack()
then i called t1.get() into the inset function but i am getting error like dateentry do not have get attribute.
this is the issue that i am facing inside my registration form GUI